# Getting back HTML from `div` element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-entities, html-encode

When I add HTML to a `div` element and later try to get it back, jQuery either removes the HTML tags or converts all applicable characters to HTML entities, depending on if I use `.html()` or `.text()`.

Here's a demonstration ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6EGC/))

```
$('div').html('<h1>Hi, Alice & Bob</h1>');
console.log('html: ' + $('div').html());
console.log('text: ' + $('div').text());
```

Console output

```
html: <h1>Hi, Alice &amp; Bob</h1>
text: Hi, Alice & Bob
```

How do I get back exactly `<h1>Hi, Alice & Bob</h1>`?

Comment: Why not `innerHTML` ?

Comment: @FSou1 As you can see in the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L131), `.html()` is based on `innerHTML`. I have, however, updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6EGC/1/) to demonstrate `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any other way to solve this other than to decode the entities like so

```
var decode = function( val ) {
  var el  = document.createElement('textarea');
      el.innerHTML = val;
  return el.value;
};
```

Here is a function that will do that for you

and usage like this

```
$('div').html('<h1>Hi, Alice & Bob</h1>');
console.log( decode( $('div').html() ) );
// Result is => <h1>Hi, Alice & Bob</h1>
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qvcq/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That does solve the actual example, but try with a string like `<h1>Hi, Alice & Bob &hellip;</h1>`.

Comment: You may wan't to check here for `hellip` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417818/html-entities-with-jquery